# How to update different views using SwiftUI?

Tags: rotation, swiftui, scenekit, swift5

I am aiming to make a program in which I am using using SwiftUI buttons to update by SCNView in SceneKit. I have a cylinder as a `SCNCylinder` in my `SCNView` inside a frame in SwiftUI. I want my cylinder to rotate about 180° after I press the button. In my current code I have used `@State` and `@Binding` to update the view. But somehow the cylinder rotates as soon as I run the code, not waiting for me to touch the button. Not sure why this happens

Here is my code :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var rotationAngle: Float = 180
      var body: some View {
       VStack{ 
          Button(action: {
            // What to perform
            self.rotationAngle = 180
        }) {
            // How the button looks like
            Text("180°")
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .position(x: 225, y: 500)
        }


        SceneKitView(angle: self.$rotationAngle)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .position(x: 225, y: 0)


    }
  } 
}

struct SceneKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var angle: Float

func degreesToRadians(_ degrees: Float) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(degrees * .pi / 180)
}

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SceneKitView>) -> SCNView {

    let sceneView = SCNView()
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    sceneView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 0, height: 1)
    return sceneView
}

func updateUIView(_ sceneView: SCNView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SceneKitView>) {


    let cylinder = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.02, height: 2.0)
    let cylindernode = SCNNode(geometry: cylinder)
    cylindernode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    cylinder.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green  

    cylindernode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -1, 0)

    let rotation = SCNAction.rotate(by: self.degreesToRadians(self.angle), around: SCNVector3(1, 0, 0), duration: 5)

    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cylindernode)


    cylindernode.runAction(rotation)


}
typealias UIViewType = SCNView

}
```

I want the cylinder to rotate after I press the button. Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

just set startingAngle to 0

```
@State var rotationAngle: Float = 0
```